# Find first row per year that meets criterion in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that keeps track of sports stats. I'm trying to make a query that will pull out just the rows with the first home game of each season. The database is set up similar to this:

```
TABLE 'STATS'
GAMENUMBER | YEAR | MONTH | DAY | OPPONENT | HOMEAWAY | ...
1          | 2010 | 9     | 7   | Yale     | A        | ...
2          | 2010 | 9     | 14  | Rice     | H        | ...
3          | 2010 | 9     | 21  | NCSU     | H        | ...
1          | 2009 | 9     | 7   | Ohio     | A        | ...
2          | 2009 | 9     | 14  | SUNY     | A        | ...
3          | 2009 | 9     | 21  | Penn     | A        | ...
1          | 2008 | 9     | 7   | Iowa     | H        | ...
...
```

I assume I need to somehow use the YEAR and GAMENUMBER columns to find the single game per year that is the first home game. But I can't get the query right! If it helps this will be called using PHP on a website to make a table showing the data.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
SELECT MIN(s.gamenumber),s.year,s.month,s.day,s.homeaway
FROM stats s
WHERE s.homeaway='H'
GROUP BY s.year
```

let me know if it works cause i can't test it right now...

Comment: I think this query will return wrong result for fields which aren't in `GROUP BY`, ie day and month - it will return **smallest** day and smallest month number, not day and month number of the smallest/first home game.

Comment: You're right! I actually didn't try this actual code (until you mentioned the error), but made my own once JB pointed me in the right direction with GROUP BY.

Comment: BTW - the code I basically ended up with was: `SELECT MIN(gamenumber), month, day, year, opponent FROM stats WHERE homeaway = 'H' GROUP BY year`.

Answer (score 1):

Query like

```
SELECT year, min(GAMENUMBER) FROM stats WHERE(HOMEAWAY = 'H') GROUP BY year
```

would get you first homegame per year but to get the rest of the row too I would try

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stats s
  JOIN(SELECT year y, min(GAMENUMBER) gn FROM stats WHERE(HOMEAWAY = 'H')GROUP BY year) q
    ON(s.year = q.year)AND(s.GAMENUMBER = q.gn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments on getting the rest of the row. After trying the GROUP BY fix I realized it wasn't returning the whole row and used a nested SELECT to get it all. But I'll drop yours in too and see which works better.

Comment: FYI, It's far better from an efficiency standpoint to join to a temporary table created by a subquery in the FROM clause (like in this example) rather than to have a dependent subquery pulling information for each row.

With an independent query in the FROM clause, the subquery is run once, and the results are cached in a temporary table to be joined in the main query.  With a dependent subquery (a query that depends on the results of the outer query in order to run), it needs to be run once for every row returned in the outer query.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery